# the objects of /pattern are not highlighted

Tags: vim

I use /pattern to find string I need in VIM, but the objects are not highlighted. The objects are captured because I can use n to find every object. They are just not highlighted.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set it with this command :
":set hlsearch"

You can desactivate it with this command : 
":nohlsearch"

For more info, you can have a look here:

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_all_search_pattern_matches

Best regards